Debian: Can you define veth in /etc/network/interfaces?
I found the following documentation for Ubuntu. Does Debian have a similar page? I'm looking for something comprehensive-- not just a few random examples. I can create veth using the ip command, so I know the support is there. Should something like this work?
auto h
iface h inet manual
  link-type veth
  veth-peer-name t


The best way to get reliable information from man pages, for your system, is to run man locally; in this case:
man 5 interfaces

Debian does publish its man pages online, you’ll find man 5 interfaces here. You can navigate to various versions of the page.
Your veth setup matches the documentation, it should work on Debian.

I guess it didn't like my short interface names of 'h' and 't'. It works as expected if I use 'head' and 'tail'.
